# Is there any difference between $\sigma((X_1,X_2))$ versus $\sigma(X_1)\cup \sigma(X_2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

For random variables $X_1,X_2$, is there any difference between $\sigma((X_1,X_2))$ versus $\sigma(X_1)\cup \sigma(X_2)$?

If not, how to explain that $(X_1,X_2)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable iff $X_1,X_2$ are $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?

Comment: Look at $A=\{a,b,c\}$, $X_1=1_{\{a\}}$ and $X_2=1_{\{c\}}$. Then $\sigma(X_1)$ and $\sigma(X_2)$ don't contain $\{b\}$. However $\sigma((X_1,X_2))$ does contain $\{b\}=(X_1,X_2)^{-1}(0,0)$.

Comment: In fact, the above is an example of a case in which $\sigma(X_1) \cup \sigma(X_2)$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra since $\{b\} = A \setminus (\{a\} \cup \{c\})$ is not in the union but of course $\{a\} \cup \{c\}$ is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For example, one of them is always a $\sigma$-algebra whilst the other isn't in general. Instead, we have $\sigma(X_1,X_2) = \sigma(\sigma(X_1)\cup \sigma(X_2))$.

Comment: But how to explain that $(X_1,X_2)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable iff $X_1,X_2$ are $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?

Comment: $(X_1,X_2)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable iff $\sigma(X_1,X_2) \subset \mathcal{F}$ iff $\sigma(\sigma(X_1)\cup \sigma(X_2)) \subset \mathcal{F}$ iff $\sigma(X_1)\cup \sigma(X_2) \subset \mathcal{F}$ since $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.